# Animation will not play

Tags: animation

Recently, I've been attempting to set up an animation in Blender with the model I've made, but for whatever reason, I cannot get the program to play the animation.

[image]

I don't know why this is happening, I set up a starting and ending key frame, but when I press the button for the animation to play, nothing happens.

Because of this problem, I need help on how I can rectify it.

EDIT: After playing around with the model a little bit, I managed set at least a couple of key frames and play an animation.  However, adding key frames is still extremely screwy, with the program deleting key frames for no apparent reason.  I still don't know what I doing wrong with setting up key frames, so I've added a link to my Blend file below.

[image]

Comment: hi, how can one possibly guess from that picture? how are the animation curves set? does it work moving manually through frames? can you share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link?

Comment: As per your suggestion, I've uploaded my Blend file for anyone to take a look at.

Comment: Hi, You missed the file link :)

Comment: I added it to my original post, unless it''s not showing up for some reason?  It's currently visible to me, and the link seems to working, as it has been apparently downloaded at least once since this post has been made.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your file: all fine! Unless I'm missing something, I suspect that you just press ALT-A or press "play" button and nothing happens... because you're starting at frame 60!!

try to start playing from frame 1 and it works...

[image]

Comment: Upon playing around with the model a little bit, my problem seems to be less to do with actually playing the animation, but rather how to apply changes to the model's positioning to the key frames.  For example, I tried to bend the model's foot as it walked to give it a more natural-looking walking cycle, but the changes I made ended up applying to the model as a whole rather than just the key frame I was trying to assign to.  This resulted in my model having the same stiff walking animation as before, just now with a bent foot instead.

Comment: I thought this following question should be its own seperate comment, so does anyone have any suggestions on how I keep the feet from spinning around in a 360-degree motion?  The feet are supposed move back and forth, not spin around in a such ridiculous manner.